# How to call a specific INT in python

Tags: python, arrays, int

To calculate `h` we must have `f1`, `f2` and `fn` for `n*n` matrix.
`f` can have every possible function, from ODE to a simple equation. I chose `xx+yy` for simplification.
How to call specific `int` which is `f` here, for example `f[2]`, and it automatically put `2` in `xx[i]+yy[i]`. `f[2]=0.14+33.8`
In general how to call a specific int like `f` as I mentioned above.

```
xx=np.array([0.1,0.12,0.14,0.16])
yy=np.array([32,33,33.8,34.1])
C=[[13,18],[28,-27]]


#f[i]=xx[i]+yy[i]


r1=[[f1,f2]]
r2=[[f1],[f2]]

m=np.dot(r1,C)
z=np.dot(m,r2)
h=np.linalg.det(z)
print('matrix=',h)
```

It can be:

```
A=xx[i]*squad(xx[i]/8)
B=odeint(def,0,A) #which is an ode
F[i]=B-yy[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function to construct f by taking the underlying function as an argument, the `const` function applies the function `func` to every couple of elements from `xx` and `yy`, so any function that accepts a tuple of floats should work.

```
def const(func):
    return list(map(func, zip(xx, yy)))

f = const(sum)
# f[2] = 33.939999999999998
```

Comment: Thank you. But the  sum was just a sample. Xx and yy may be in every possible function. Ode, intrgrals and... . Your code just is for summation.

Comment: The question has been Updated

Answer (score 0):

the main thing in ur code is `def new_calculation(n):`

from math import *
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.integrate import quad
    from scipy.integrate import odeint
    min=l=m=n=k=t=dec=chi=chiB=chiCMB=hh=cpl=None

```
xx=np.array([0.01,0.012,0.014,0.016])
yy=np.array([32.95388698,33.87900347,33.84214074,34.11856704])
z = [0.01, 0.012]  # new list

Cov=[[137,168],[28155,-2217]]


def ant(z,O_m,O_D):           
    return 1/sqrt(((1+z)**2)*(1+O_m*z)-z*(2+z)*O_D)

def HDE(y,z):
    a=1/(1+z)        
    dydz = -y*((((H0*(3*b-3+g)*O_m*(a**(3*b-3+g)))/y**2)-(g**3)*w*(a**(-2*g))/3)/(2*(1-g-0.166*(g**2)*w*(a**(-2*g))))-2*(c**2)*(1-1/(2*rc*y)))*a
    return dydz

def new_calculation(n):
    yn = odeint(HDE,y0,[z0,z[n]])  # z[n] takes values from new list
    yyn=yn[-1,0]
    O_Dn=1-O_m-(1/(2*rc*yyn))
    q=quad(ant,0,z[n],args=(O_m,O_Dn))[0]     
    h=log10((1+z[n])*(299000/70)*q)+25     
    fn=(yy[n]-M-h)
    return fn


H0=70
M=2
w=20
b=0.04
O_m=0.27
rc=0.09
c=0.7
for G in range (1,2):
        g=0.1*G  # where is this 'g' used ?

        y0=H0
        z0=0

        f_list = []
        for i in range(2):  # the value '2' reflects matrix size
            f_list.append(new_calculation(i))

        rdag=[f_list]
        rmat=[[f] for f in f_list]

        mm=np.dot(rdag,Cov)
        zz=np.dot(mm,rmat)
        hh=np.linalg.det(zz)*0.000001 

        print('Minimum chi^2 =',hh)
```

Comment: I hope it helps